Pnpm sudden memory leak, not creating node_modules folder or pnpm-lock.yaml file
I've been working on two separate, but related projects. One acts as a pretty large monorepo, which has 40+ packages that all provide the necessary components and API related stuff to make the other single Next/React application work.
I spent the past ~week trying to resolve some issues within the monorepo, so I haven't attempted a build in the single, really pretty simple app that utilizes everything from the monorepo. Yesterday, out of nowhere the CLI build script that targets the simple, single application repeatedly ran out of memory, and after some inspection, the issue is actually with pnpm install and not the script at all.
This single app is really pretty simple, as most of the logic is handled by the monorepo, but all of a sudden pnpm fails to create a node_modules folder, a pnpm-lock.yaml file, and eventually runs out of memory and produces the heap allocation reached error. I've tried every .npmrc configuration I can think of, and I still can't get pnpm to create the proper files. I've even deleted every pnpm related file on my system and reinstalled from scratch to the latest, but still I get this same memory heap issue, and to make matters worse, I'm stuck working on horrendous WIFI and am wrapping up the build script, which involves repeatedly downloading things from npm.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really can't make any progress at all until I figure out this disaster...
